# Basic HTACCESS Issue

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed WAMPSERVER on my system. Inside the htdocs folder, i have my project folder which is named 'online-store'

so to access my project i write

```
http://localhost/online-store
```

I want all requests like

```
http://locahost/online-store/products/2 or http://localhost/online-store/products/
```

to be redirected to api.php.
I have written the htaccess code for that but it says

```
/online-store/products url was not found on the system.
```

I am rewriting htaccess to make it a restful API.
Below is my HTACCESS CODE.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to place this code in `htdocs/online-store/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /online-store/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It says "The requested URL /online-store/products was not found on this server."

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is the location of above .htaccess?

Comment: This is the only .htaccess. Yes, this is the only code in the HTACCESS. The location is C:/Wamp/www/htdocs/online-store/.htaccess

Comment: Is `products` a valid file or directory?

Comment: No, there is no directory named products. Nor any file is there which is named products.

Comment: So you can load this URL: `http://site.com/online-store/api.php?request=products` ?

Comment: Make sure if your `.htaccess` is enabled by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generated 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Yes i can load this URL. Will just check if htaccess is enabled or not.

Comment: I do get the internal server error. Means the HTACCESS is enabled.

Comment: ok try removing both `RewriteCond` lines and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: No difference in removing both RewriteCond Lines.

Comment: Then last suspicion is that mod_rewrite isn't enabled. If you comment `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` lines then probably you will get 500 internal error.

Comment: It finally worked. Mod_rewrite was not enabled. Thank you so much. Any idea how could it have got disabled?

Comment: Probably while upgrading/installing Apache it could have happened.

Comment: Do u have any good resources for learning how to design a restful api in php?

Comment: Yes see these 2 links: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/ and http://davss.com/tech/php-rest-api-frameworks/ for readymade PHP frameworks

Comment: Hi Anubhava. I just have a small doubt with the Corey Maynard Link. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: yes sure in case you want to write email `anubhava[AT]aol[DOT]com`

Comment: I have sent you the mail. :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to change code in httpd.conf

wampdir/bin/apache/apache2.x.x./conf/httpd.conf

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Still does not work.It says "The requested URL /online-store/products was not found on this server."

Comment: can you try without "-" in project name

Comment: Tried removing "-". No difference.